# my phone keeps on displaying "sorry we cannot play this file on your phone"

Tags: video, 7.x

When I try and play videos off the internet (YouTube especially) it comes up with "sorry we cannot play this file on your phone" on my music+videos app

I have unticked "connect with Zune" it plays a couple of videos but then it stops playing altogether

And also does windows phone 7.8 have a in browser player like android?

Comment: Which phone/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using a Nokia lumia 610